# Why is my applescript for checking if a file exists failing?

Tags: applescript

I have an applescript application that inputs a username and starts a download based on that username. In the app I use the code below to check if a file exists already and then rename the file if it does.

```
tell application "Finder"
if exists "~/Downloads/Conversion/" & cbUsername & ".flv" as POSIX file then
    set x to 1
    repeat
        set newCbFilename to cbUsername & "_" & x as string
        if exists "~/Downloads/Conversion/" & newCbFilename & ".flv" as POSIX file then
            set x to x + 1
        else
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat
    copy newCbFilename to finalCbFilename
    display dialog "Filename already exists " & "File will be named: " & finalCbFilename & ".flv" buttons "OK" default button "OK" with title "Error" with icon caution
else
    copy cbUsername to finalCbFilename
end if
end tell
```

All of a sudden yesterday it stopped working correctly. I had added the following code to ensure that the folder I was saving to existed.

```
tell application "System Events"
if not (exists folder "~/Downloads/Conversion") then
    do shell script "mkdir ~/Downloads/Conversion"
end if
```

Even when I comment out that code now it still doesn't work. What did I do wrong?
    end tell

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the Finder needs the absolute path to the home folder instead of the relative path. Instead of starting the path with `~/`, it needs to start with `/Users/username/`.

Instead of hardcoding the username into the script, you can have AppleScript build the absolute path on the fly:

```
set homePath to POSIX path of (path to home folder)
```

Then you can replace `"~/` with `homePath & "`

For example:

```
if exists "~/Downloads/Conversion/" & cbUsername & ".flv" as POSIX file then
```

would become

```
if exists homePath & "Downloads/Conversion/" & cbUsername & ".flv" as POSIX file then
```

Alternatively, if you only use `~` with the path `~/Downloads/Conversion/`, you could instead change that whole path to a variable:

```
set cbPath to POSIX path of (path to home folder) & "Downloads/Conversion/"
```

Then the final script would be:

```
set cbPath to POSIX path of (path to home folder) & "Downloads/Conversion/"

tell application "Finder"
    if exists cbPath & cbUsername & ".flv" as POSIX file then
        set x to 1
        repeat
            set newCbFilename to cbUsername & "_" & x as string
            if exists cbPath & newCbFilename & ".flv" as POSIX file then
                set x to x + 1
            else
                exit repeat
            end if
        end repeat
        copy newCbFilename to finalCbFilename
        display dialog "Filename already exists " & "File will be named: " & finalCbFilename & ".flv" buttons "OK" default button "OK" with title "Error" with icon caution
    else
        copy cbUsername to finalCbFilename
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: Alright, I'll try this. I'm just curious why it decided to stop working now is all. It worked fine up until I added the code I mentioned. O_o

Comment: @EliGreenberg if the answer did answer your question please mark it as the accepted answer.